# YouTube Full screen control not showing

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, dom-events

I am dynamically adding an <iframe> and adding a YouTube video. The YouTube player working fine but the full screen controls are not showing.

The code is:

```
var newIframe = $("<iframe width='80px' height='80px' "
  + "src='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3TtgYuaVFk' "
  + "frameborder='0' allowfullscreen id='vid" + mindBoxID + "'>");
var tmp = "#"+mindBoxID;
$(tmp).append(newIframe);
```

Answer (score 2):

You `src` URL is wrong, use `src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/r3TtgYuaVFk'` instead.

```
var newIframe = $("<iframe width='80px' height='80px' "
  + "src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/r3TtgYuaVFk' "
  + "frameborder='0' allowfullscreen id='vid" + mindBoxID + "'>");
var tmp = "#"+mindBoxID;
$(tmp).append(newIframe);
```

The documentation on <iframe> embedded videos is available here https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Manual_IFrame_Embeds